# Bypass ionic 2 component and use default html tag

Tags: ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

Let's say I want to create a custom `button` element that extends the default html `button` tag.

My `component` would look more or less like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-button',
  styles: []
  template: `<button><ng-content></ng-content></button>`
})
export class MyButton{}
```

The issue is that instead of a regular HTML button, I get the ionic2 button. How can I bypass the ionic 2 button component and create my own?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with an `anchor` element?

```
<a class="my-button"><ng-content></ng-content></a>
```

and some *default button* styles like these (or the styles you want to apply to it):

```
a.my-button {
    align-items: flex-start;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: default;
    color: buttontext;
    border-image-source: initial;
    border-image-slice: initial;
    border-image-width: initial;
    border-image-outset: initial;
    border-image-repeat: initial;
    background-color: buttonface;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 2px 6px 3px;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: outset;
    border-color: buttonface;
    padding: 1px 6px;
    text-rendering: auto;
    color: initial;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-spacing: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    text-indent: 0px;
    text-shadow: none;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: start;
    margin: 0em 0em 0em 0em;
    font: 13.3333px Arial;
}
```